# How do I reduce lag when loading image with URLSession?

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

There is a lag in loading the UIImageView called profilePic. How can I get rid of this lag?

The problem seems to be in my addImage() method.

```swift
    
    private func addImage() {
        let donorId = donor.lastName
        guard let urlString = self.defaults.value(forKey: "url\(donorId)") as? String,
              let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                self.donorsViewController.handle(error)
                return
            }
 
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.profilePic.image = image
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Note: I tried adding the dataTask method to the main thread, but it didn't substantially improve the lag.

Comment: I've seen on SO and elsewhere recommendations for third party apis (such as SDWebImage or Kingfisher) to handle the change and loading of images. Would one of these be advised, and if so which one?

Comment: There is a lag, because asking an image from a remote server might take times. SDWebImage, KingFisher, Alamofire+Image are good libs (you can use the one you want), but it won't fix lag if you have a bad connection. They cache images too.

Comment: Hi @Larme, thanks, I added KingFisher and it sorted out the lag.